# Get sum of a column by grouping based on a range given in 2 columns

Tags: sql, group-by, range

I have a sql command that gives me results in the following columns

```
start_date, end_date, count, weekday
```

I want to get, for each start_date, the sum of the count from the start_date to its end_date where weekdays match.

So for example, if I have a row with `start_date = 2012 01 01` and `end_date = 2012 08 08` and `weekday = Tuesday`, I want to find all the other rows that have the a start_date that falls within that range AND that its a Tuesday, then find the sum of the counts. How can I achieve that?

E.g. From this table

```
Start       ||  End         ||Count||  Weekday
2012-01-01  ||  2012-12-12  ||  5  ||  Tuesday
2012-05-05  ||  2012-12-12  ||  7  ||  Tuesday
2012-06-06  ||  2012-10-10  ||  2  ||  Wednesday
2012-07-07  ||  2012-08-08  ||  8  ||  Wednesday
2012-09-09  ||  2012-10-10  ||  9  ||  Tuesday
```

It should return

```
date        |  sum_count
2012-01-01  |  16    // count of 2012-05-05 + 2012-09-09 (Tuesdays only)
2012-05-05  |  9
2012-06-06  |  8
2012-07-07  |  0
2012-09-09  |  0
```

Comment: can you please go to sqlfiddle.com and generate your schema and put some test records in it that way we can validate these queries?

Comment: How do you import from sql fiddle?

Comment: just post the hyperlink.  We can access it via that.

Answer (score 1):

Without a fiddle, [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com) it will be hard to correctly get this the first try.  But what you want to do is something along these lines:

```
   select count(*), * 
   from  
   (
    select *  
    from  
       (  
           select start_date,end_date,weekday  
           from  table  
           where start_date >= timestamp('2012 01 01')  
           and end_date <=  timestamp('2012 08 08')  
        )  
       where weekday = 'Tuesday'  
    );
```

The objective is to reduce your result set each time, by keeping `weekday` in a separate subquery you can potentially avoid a costly join or 2.

**Question**

> huh? I still don't understand though. 2012 08 08, 2012 01 01 and
>   Tuesday are from the input table, and there are multiple rows that I
>   need to process. Are you saying that processing each row separately is
>   more efficient?

You have to process each row individually, unless you know someway to avoid a full table scan when searching against dates.  This hinges on comparing the explain plans, which we do not have as we are still awaiting your fiddle.
The key to this is the inner most query will give you the date range that you want, with all the days of the week.  It is more efficient (most of the time), to then execute against the more specific where clause, in your case the day of the week.  The reason for this is the database (most modern ones do this) tries to order the data in such a way that it can return as quickly as possible.

**Extra update**

As a real world example of this, I have a table with close to ~1 billion entries in it that I must run an analytic function over.  The first way I did this was as so:

```
select *   
from  
(  
        select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by seen desc) rn  
        from foo  
)where rn =1  
 and status = 1
```

The above would take about 9 minutes to execute.  When I modified the query to be this:

```
select *
from   
(   select *   
    from  
    (  
            select *, row_number() over (partition by id order by seen desc) rn  
            from foo  
    )where status = 1  
) where status = 1
```

it returns in just under 1 minute.  This is an example where I carefully reduced the size of the driving result set so that the system would do less work and thus return more quickly.

Comment: The query is right but the comment at the end makes no sense.  SQL is a declarative language, not a procedural language.  Almost any query engine will combine the conditions into a single scan on the data, filtering as the data is read.

Comment: With this, don't I have to run separate SQL queries for each row in the input table?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to use SQLfiddle meanwhile.

Comment: so the way SQL works is via sets.  You want to reduce your set as much as possible that way the outer queries have less data to process.  So your least restrictive clause is the start_date / end_date piece.

Comment: huh? I still don't understand though. 2012 08 08, 2012 01 01 and Tuesday are from the input table, and there are multiple rows that I need to process. Are you saying that processing each row separately is more efficient?

Comment: @user1916371 Responded in my post

Comment: @user1916371 I have provided my real worldy example to show how performance can be increased.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I believe self join is the best option

```
  select b.start_date,nvl(sum(a.Count),0) from TABLE2 a right join TABLE2 b on 
  a.start_date<>b.start_date and
  a.weekday=b.weekday and a.start_date between b.start_date and b.end_date 
  group by b.start_date order by b.start_date
```

[fiddledemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2019f/20)

Comment: hmm is `between` sql standard?

Comment: For minimum records we can use it but for large records we can use operators.

Comment: Ah okay. What if input table (table1) that I have is actually a select statement it self? How do I alias that as table b?

Comment: yeah then you can join weekday in self join. Let me edit my answer for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

i Hope this is your requirement... this one works in oracle with your sample data

```
  select TAB.START_DATE START_DATE, nvl(X1.SUM_COUNT,0) SUM_COUNT
     from TABLE2 TAB,
        ( select A1.START_DATE,SUM(A2.COUNT) SUM_COUNT
          from TABLE2 A1,TABLE2 A2
          where A1.WEEKDAY=A2.WEEKDAY and A1.rowid <> A2.rowid
          and A2.START_DATE between A1.START_DATE and A1.END_DATE
          group by A1.START_DATE
       ) X1
    where TAB.START_DATE=X1.START_DATE(+) order by 1
```

please refer this sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2019f/4